# Query to back up a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, backup

I made a CRUD web application that uses a small PostgreSQL database. It is a donors database with the columns name, telephone, blood type, etc.

I have some `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO` queries, but now I need a query to back up the database. Nobody has asked about it on this site before, so I think it can't be done, or else I have to make a script using pg_dump or a maintenance plan).

Is it possible to write a SQL query to perform a PostgreSQL database backup?

Comment: You can use pgAdmin - or take a file system backup(with database shut  down (`tar -cf backup.tar /usr/local/pgsql/data`). If your file is small (size?), this will probably be good enough. I presume that you have a paper trail (forms filled in) of your data?

Comment: I use pgAdmin but I need a query that can perform a database backup. I tried to execute this SQL sentence **pg_dump donation > donation_backup** but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because pg_dump **isn't** an SQL "sentence" (or statement) - it's a separate programme (like mysqldump). You can run it as a cron job. What's the matter with pgAdmin? Or my other suggestion of a cold backup?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL does not generate a database backup using a query as SQL Server does (ex: *backup database [db_name] to disk...*)! It is a different RDBMS; you can't simply do something that other one does, just because you want!

There are 2 methods to take backups from Postgres as commented before. Using *pg_dump*, you can produce a full sql file including all DDL and DML statements to recreate your database in another place (or restore):

```
pg_dump -Fp -v -h YOUR_HOST -U YOUR_LOGIN -d DATABASE_NAME -f your_file_name.sql
```

[PostgreSQL pg_dump documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

Or you can take physical backups by copying the *pg_data* folder.

It's up to you decide!

Answer (score 0):

If your PostgreSQL database is on Windows, you can create a batch file to automate backups.

1. Create a folder and save the pg_dump job (example files below) as a `<backup_job_name>.bat` file.
2. Go to task scheduler and schedule a basic task pointing to the batch file to run your backup at specified times.

#### Edit this example batch file for multiple databases

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set PostgreSQL bin directory path
set PG_BIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"

rem Set PostgreSQL database connection parameters
set PG_HOST=localhost
set PG_PORT=5432
set PG_USER=your_username
set PG_PASSWORD=your_password

rem List of databases to back up
set DATABASES=db1 db2 db3

rem Set the backup destination directory
set BACKUP_DIR=C:\Path\To\Backup

rem Set the timestamp for backup and log file
set TIMESTAMP=!date:~10,4!!date:~4,2!!date:~7,2!-!time:~0,2!!time:~3,2!

rem Loop through each database and create a backup
for %%D in (%DATABASES%) do (
    set PG_DB=%%D

    rem Set the log file path with timestamp
    set LOG_FILE=%BACKUP_DIR%\backup_log_!PG_DB!_%TIMESTAMP%.txt

    rem Set the backup file path with timestamp
    set BACKUP_FILE=%BACKUP_DIR%\backup_!PG_DB!_%TIMESTAMP%.backup

    rem Create a full backup using pg_dump and log the process
    %PG_BIN%\pg_dump.exe -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% -d !PG_DB! -F c -b -v -f !BACKUP_FILE! > !LOG_FILE! 2>&1

    echo Backup for !PG_DB! completed at %TIMESTAMP%. >> !LOG_FILE!
)
```

---

#### Edit this example batch file for a single database

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set PostgreSQL bin directory path
set PG_BIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"

rem Set PostgreSQL database connection parameters
set PG_HOST=localhost
set PG_PORT=5432
set PG_USER=your_username
set PG_PASSWORD=your_password
set PG_DB=your_database_name

rem Set the backup destination directory
set BACKUP_DIR=C:\Path\To\Backup

rem Set the timestamp for backup and log file
set TIMESTAMP=!date:~10,4!!date:~4,2!!date:~7,2!-!time:~0,2!!time:~3,2!

rem Set the log file path with timestamp
set LOG_FILE=%BACKUP_DIR%\backup_log_%TIMESTAMP%.txt

rem Set the backup file path with timestamp
set BACKUP_FILE=%BACKUP_DIR%\backup_%TIMESTAMP%.backup

rem Create a full backup using pg_dump and log the process
%PG_BIN%\pg_dump.exe -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% -d %PG_DB% -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% > %LOG_FILE% 2>&1

echo Backup completed at %TIMESTAMP%. >> %LOG_FILE%
```

Answer (score -1):

Use pg_dump from command line. the pg_dump exe is in your bin folder inside the Postgres installation directory.

```
sudo pg_dump -F c -b -v --dbname=postgresql://myuser:mypassword@lcoalhost:5432/mydbname > /home/ubuntu/mydatabase.backup (or mydatabase.sql)
```